# Immutable lexical scope data structure

Tags: lexical-analysis

I'm working on a mini lisp and now I'm wonder about scopes. For my case I'll have this constructs that introduce scopes.

- lambdas introduce it's arguments
- let binds
- and modules

The way I worked on this was, a single scope is an associate array, and all scopes are stacked from inner to out. Also I have a global scope that is read only (only builtins), and finally a lookup function that lookups for a symbol in all scopes in the right order.

During the evaluation, when something introduces a scope, for example a function call, I push the variables to the scope stack and then evaluate the body. I want to get rid of this mutation because it makes hard to parallelize the evaluator (the scope stack is a global in my interpreter).

I couldn't find any formal definition of scope or anything like that, closer I get was E register from SECD machine.

Does anybody know any work done in this direction? Having references would be nice to have some insights

Comment: `the scope stack is a global in my interpreter` - Use immutable (persistent) stack?

Comment: hi @Dmitry I was thinking about using a kind of composition on scopes, since the scopes are the composition of each individual scope, but I'm out of lucky on modeling that. You mean use an imutable stack, like always replace old global by a new instance without mutating in place?

Comment: Yes. Essentially, you can use lists (the way they are implemented in e.g. Haskell)

Comment: I'll need to implement them in a efficient way, I'm using VimL (lmao)